# How to use LEAD and LAG In Where?

Tags: sql-server, lag, lead

i have a table like this:

```
Number   Price    Type       Date         Time
------   -----    ----    ----------    ---------
23456    0,665     SV     2014/02/02     08:00:02
23457    1,3       EC     2014/02/02     07:50:45
23460    0,668     SV     2014/02/02     07:36:34
23461    0,668     SV     2014/02/02     07:37:34
23462    0,668     SV     2014/02/02     07:38:34
23463    0,668     SV     2014/02/02     07:39:34
```

For each record I need previous/next  price. In this case, the query is simple.

```
Select Lag(price) over (order by date desc, time desc),
Lead(price) over (order by date desc, time desc)
from ITEMS
```

but i need the result Where Next price <> record price

My Query is

```
    Select Lag(price) over (order by date desc, time desc) Nxt_Price,
    Lead(price) over (order by date desc, time desc) Prv_Price
    from ITEMS
 Where Nxt_Price <> price
```

but it refused to use that variable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the below query:

```
SELECT Nxt_Price, Prv_Price 
FROM
    (Select price, Lag(price) over (order by date desc, time desc) Nxt_Price,
    Lead(price) over (order by date desc, time desc) Prv_Price
    from ITEMS) AS InnerQuery
 Where Nxt_Price <> price
```

It may help you.

Comment: could u plz explain why that works using 'inner_Query' ?

Comment: It is not inner join, It is Sub query. The columns Nxt_Price and Prv_Price are created only inside the innerQuery. It is not possible to access them in the same query. So, we need to use another 'select' query to use the values of Nxt_Price and Prv_Price.

Answer (score 7):

Use a common table expression.

```
with myItems as (
    select
       Lag(price) over (order by date desc, time desc) Nxt_Price,
       Lead(price) over (order by date desc, time desc) Prv_Price
    from ITEMS
)
select *
from myItems
where Nxt_Price <> Prv_Price
```